# Колонтитулы в HTML странице при печати

Tags: html, css, print

хочу сделать колонтитулы на печати HTML страниц

```
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
     @media print {
      @page:left{
        @bottom-left {
        content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
      }
    }
    }
        </STYLE>
```

Почему то не срабатывает, или я что-то не правильно делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос уже был.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664752/how-to-add-print-headers-and-footers-in-html-css-and-javascript
или
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664752/how-to-add-print-headers-and-footers-in-html-css-and-javascript

Прямого решения нет. Можно использовать таблицы с фиксированной высотой, что конечно не удобно в плане редактирования содержимого или использовать pdf где вы можете контролировать как выглядит страница.

Comment: а варианта использовать разметку вида выше - нет? http://www.princexml.com/doc/9.0/page-numbers/

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#page-box - вот вроде есть такая спецификация для CSS....

Comment: в целом понятно! тогда два под вопроса - чтобы не дублировать - имеет ли смысл удалить вопрос? каким бесплатным способом генерить простейший PDF средствами php, желательно, чтобы оно просто преобразовывало HTML->PDF т.е. я подаю HTML разметку, и оно нормально отображается как PDF файл

Comment: По поводу простейшего генератора, как то сам не сталкивался, но это очень избитая тема в интернете - https://www.jelu.ru/2009/11/11.html, или вот на хабре например - https://habrahabr.ru/post/31438/